# Unable to upload different directory's file to server by using socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to upload a file to the server from my client program. I can successfully upload a file that are from the same directory. But whenever I upload file from a different directory , it doesn't recognize the file and show File doesn't exists. Does anyone could point out what im doing wrong right here? thanks in advance

**Image (When i upload file from desktop):**
[image]

**My client code:**

```
def uploadfiletoserver():
    try:
        # open file selector
        directory = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Please select a directory')
        filename = (os.path.basename(directory))
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            s.send(str("fup~" + filename).encode("utf-8"))
            s.send(str.encode("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))))
            filesize = int(os.path.getsize(filename))
            userResponse = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    s.send(bytesToSend)
                    totalSend = len(bytesToSend)
                    while int(totalSend) < int(filesize):
                        bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                        totalSend += len(bytesToSend)
                        s.send(bytesToSend)
                        sys.stdout.write("\r|" + "█" * int((totalSend / float(filesize)) * 50) + "|{0:.2f}".format(
                            (totalSend / float(filesize)) * 100) + "%  ")
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                    print("\nUpload Completed!")
        else:
            print("File Does Not Exist!")
    except:
        print("Error")
```

**My server code:**

```
# send file

def fup(filename, conn):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        conn.send(str.encode("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))))
        filesize = int(os.path.getsize(filename))
        userResponse = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                conn.send(bytesToSend)
                totalSend = len(bytesToSend)
                while int(totalSend) < int(filesize):
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    totalSend += len(bytesToSend)
                    conn.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        conn.send("ERROR".encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stripping out the path with `filename = (os.path.basename(directory))`; this returns just the filename. So, `os.path.isfile(filename)` will fail unless the file is in your current directory.

You probably just want this:

```
filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Please select a directory')
```

Comment: I tried with this but unfortunately it return me `arr = pickle.loads(s.recv(1024))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'E'.` It said upload complete, but my server didnt receive any files

Comment: @JacksonLim So, that's the next problem for you to solve. The reason for your original error *is* the fact that you were using `basename()`.